# Datagridview Show pictures from path that is from the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

Here is my current table. Instead of the path being shown, I would like to see the image that's in the path.

[image: Pic 1]

I have already tried the one you have provided thats already here. But this would be the result

[image: Pic 2]

On the other side I have just tried two mock ups of different tables if I can see what would be the problem, but still no luck

[image: Pic 3]

Comment: try to use `DataGridViewImageColumn` to display picture in your image coulmn

Comment: @ershoaib yup, I tried that too already, still none

Comment: This path only works on one computer because it's stored on one computer not database. Is the image file is exist on the path in the computer that you try to run program?

Comment: @AdinugrahaTawaqal yup, if I use run or through my browser, I can access the file

Comment: when you debug, what is the value in `kryptonDataGridView1Columnd[5].ToString()` ?

Comment: @AdinugrahaTawaqal I don't know why but it says null

Comment: try to change your code to `  private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewImageColumn)
        {
            string imagePath = (e.Value ?? "").ToString().Trim();
            if (imagePath != "")
                e.Value = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
        }
    }` https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2343891f-59ea-482f-8a5e-e9aa68eacd81/databound-datagridviewimagecolumn?forum=winformsdesigner

Comment: CellFormatting doesn't need to use foreach they will be repeated automatically based on how many row and column.

Comment: Sure, ill check that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [info here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2343891f-59ea-482f-8a5e-e9aa68eacd81/databound-datagridviewimagecolumn?forum=winformsdesigner), try to change your code to

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, 
DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) 
{ 
if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewImageColumn) 
{ 
string imagePath = (e.Value ?? "").ToString().Trim(); 
if (imagePath != "") 
e.Value = Image.FromFile(imagePath); 
} 
}
```

also `CellFormatting` doesn't need to use foreach they will be repeated automatically based on how many row and column.